# Maven is not putting generated jars into the local repository

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I recently did a pull on the local repository. I ran into some missing dependencies, nothing unusual there. I ran `mvn clean -U install` on the projects concerned, no problem, everything looks good in maven on the command line. I refresh my projects in eclipse, no joy, eclipse says I'm missing dependencies.
After a bit of messing around back and forth with no success, I looked in the local repository itself. Sure enough, many of the required dependencies are missing; they are however, located in the target folder.
I've tried building with `install` a number of times, but the jars aren't placed in the local repository, so my other projects can't find them.
Sometimes a later version of the library is there, but not an earlier on, for example `6.0.28-SNAPSHOT` is there but not `6.0.27-SNAPSHOT`. 
I have checked my settings in eclipse and maven:

- Eclipse is using the correct version of maven
- They both have the same local repository
- They are both using the same `settings.xml` file
- They are both using the same version of Java

Since all the jars I checked appear to be in the target folder, I think the issue is with maven not installing them into the local repository. What could cause this issue, and how can i resolve it?

Also, although I don't think this is relevant myself, as everything has been working fine before, my target directory is a completely separate folder, and is not a sub-folder of each project. It's located in `C:\Maven\target`.

Comment: What plugin do you use for maven integration in eclipse?

Comment: Have you run a search on all your harddisk to make sure it does not copy your artifacts to an unexpected location?

Comment: @Axel m2e 1.7.1... I do most of my compiling and deployment from the command line.

Comment: @StephaneM No, I haven't. I'll do that now. Although the 4 or 5 missing jars that I checked are all in the target folder, just not the local repo.

Comment: @StephaneM I've searched for two of them now, they show up in the target folder, but also as a part of another jar, which could be correct?

Comment: @StephaneM this is what the second urls look like `C:\Maven\target\myapi-web-6.27.0-SNAPSHOT\target\myapi-web-6.27.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\lib` this looks odd doesn't it?

Comment: OK maybe that path doesn't look so weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to run:

`mvn eclipse:eclipse`

After pulling the updates from git.